# Why can't I adjust the label size on a Zebra GK420T?

Tags: windows-7, label-printer, zebra-printer

I have a Zebra GK420T connected to a Windows 7 host with 2" x 2" label stock using the stock ZDesigner driver.  Whenever I print a document to the printer, only the top 1.2" prints.  No matter what settings I adjust, I cannot get the bottom 0.8" to print.

- Printing to the same printer from another computer works
- Printing to the same printer when logged on as another user on the same computer works
- Printing a configuration label shows that it is correctly calibrated and prints along the entire height of the label
- The printer settings all appear correctly configured in both **Printer Properties → Advanced → Printing Defaults** and in **Preferences**
- All tests are conducted with Notepad configured for 0 margin in **File → Page Setup**
- Deleting the printer and re-creating it does not resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The print settings were corrupt in the user profile of the user trying to print.  Any of the following resolved the issue:

1. Deleting the user's profile in **System → Advanced System Settings → User Profile Settings**
2. Deleting the entries for the printer in the affected users's registry.  (Located in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModePerUser`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModes2`, and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Settings`)
3. Deleting the printer and creating one with a new name that had never been used before.

Comment: This is the most common cause and resolution to the problem. It can occur with any model of Zebra printer that uses the ZDesigner drivers. I have personally seen the issue with Z series, S, GK series and various 430 and 440 models. It is totally non-obvious that the ZDesigner drivers will re-use the (corrupt) settings if the re-installed printer has the same name. The other problem with the ZDesigner drivers is that some settings can get mixed up if multiple users on the same computer use different settings. The drivers will use the latest settings set (regardless of user) continued....

Comment: continued... It seems that in some cases for some settings (including label width/height) the settings are saved to the global registry in stead of current-user. This is a long-standing (I logged complaints about this back in 2006 already!) issue with ZDesigner drivers that still seems to crop up. At least they have the printer-handle leak on every label printed solved. Discovered that one in 2002. Got fixed in the 2012 drivers. After 10.000 labels the handles are all used and the print-spooler crashes. Really funny on a warehouse system.

Comment: @Tonny, all the while displaying the intended values, of course.

Comment: Oh yes. It showed the right values and used the wrong ones. Including mixing inches and cm's. Really nice if you got European and US users on the same system with different regional settings.